# How to add values from DE to button in email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, contactbuilder

I have a problem.
In my email template I have a button in "href" which should pull up a link from a certain field.
(I have emails in my extension and each email has its own link)

So, I found out that this can be done in the following way [AMPscript won't execute inside of an <a> tag's href](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213268/ampscript-wont-execute-inside-of-an-a-tags-href)

But I can't edit the html code of the button, it doesn't save the changes. How can this be done or is there another way?
[image]

Comment: I noticed that when "href" contains a reference to the field %%Field%% and this field have a link to the resource (saved in DE). Then, when sending a test email from the Content Builder itself, when Track Clicks is disabled, the button opens the site normally, if Track Clicks is left enabled, then when you click on the button, there will be an error opening the site, why is that?

Comment: You should use %%=Redirectto(Attributevalue(‘deeplink’))=%%

Comment: @lukas-lunow did you mean href="%%=Redirectto(Attributevalue(‘deeplink’))=%%"?

Comment: Yes, @Slavik - this will ensure a robust solution, which should track your links

Comment: I tried to follow your advice, pasted your code into the button Link URL but it didn't work.
1) Used %%=Redirectto(Attributevalue('deeplink'))=%%, it didn't help
2) Used %%=Redirectto(Attributevalue('%%deeplink%%')), didn't help either
3) Used %%=Redirectto(Attributevalue(%%deeplink%%)) also didn't work.

Comment: @lukas-lunow , I was given two errors depending on the spelling of the link
1)This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
2) We cannot direct you to the requested web page at this time. Please try again.

Could this be a problem with the links themselves that are stored in the box (https/http/or no http)?

Comment: This is difficult to debug, not having insights into how deeplink is formatted. You need the full URL (https://www.example.com/category/page) stored in that DE field.

Comment: Yes, I have the full URL, but I dont understand why when I clicked on this button, I have error redirect.

Comment: @lukas-lunow I noticed that if Track Click enabled, it modify my url and maybe because of that I have error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the Tracking Alias filed was empty, in which case the value would be taken from the link URL. Since I had a link URL with % signs, this blocked the opening of the site.
Here is the documentation, in paragraph 5 it is described.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_add_button.htm&type=5